# What is the idiomatic way of returning the next member in collection?

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way of returning the next item in collection, given a member in a collection?

For example, given `(def coll [:a :b :c :d :e :f])`, what should the `f` be to make `(f coll :d)` return `:e`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @amalloy said in his answer, this isn't something for which you would want to use the original data structure, because it would require a linear lookup every time. In other words, your `(f coll :d)` pattern wouldn't be a particularly useful thing due to its performance.

However, what you could do is define a function that, given a collection, builds a data structure that makes this sort of lookup efficient, and use that as your function. It might look something like this:

```
(defn after [xs]
  (into {} (map vec (partition 2 1 xs))))
```

Examples:

```
(-> [:a :b :c :d :e :f] after :d)
;;=> :e

(let [xs [:a :b :c :d :e :f]
      f (after xs)]
  (map f xs))
;;=> (:b :c :d :e :f nil)
```

Answer (score 11):

Typically this is just not a thing one does very much in Clojure. The only possible implementation requires a linear scan of the input collection, which means that you are using the wrong data structure for this task.

Instead, we usually try to structure our data so that it is convenient for the tasks we need to perform on it. How best to do this will depend on *why* you want to look up "the element after foo". For example, if you are going through the input one item at a time and want to know the next item as well as the current item, you could write `(partition 2 1 input)` to get a sequence of pairs of adjacent values.

That is, you ask for an idiomatic implementation, but there is none: the idiom is to solve the problem differently. Of course it is straightforward to write the loop yourself, if you believe you are in an exceptional case where you are using the right data structure and just need to do this weird thing once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

If we generalise the problem to finding the thing following the first thing to pass a test, we get something like

```
(defn following [pred coll]
  (->> coll
       (drop-while (complement pred))
       (second)))
```

For example,

```
(following #{6} (range))
=> 7
```

Or, your example,

```
(following #{:d} coll)
=> :e
```

This is no more or less idiomatic than `take-while` or `drop-while`.